# how to show image instead of text with link

Tags: php, yii2

This my grid view

```
echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $provider,
            'columns' => [
                'name',
            ]
        ]);
```

it will showing name of file with location , But i want to show if file is pdf ,pdf image will show , if file is doc doc image will show with download option, I can do code for downloading the file but i don't know how to show image and download link instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this way:

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
        'columns' => [
            'name',
            [
                'attribute' => 'url',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
                    return Html::img($dataProvider->url, ['class' => 'img- rounded'], ['alt' => '']);
                }
            ],
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
        'columns' => [
            'name',
            'imageColumn:image',
            'urlColumn:url'
        ]
    ]);
```